# How to redirect after session timeout in MVC .Net?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

I want to redirect my page after 2 minutes of inactivity, for this I am using the below code to ping the controller every 2.5 minutes and if the session has expired I redirect to the original login page:

```
`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var ReqTime =@Session.Timeout
        ReqTime = ReqTime * 60 * 1000 + (.5 * 60 * 1000);
    $(function () {
    setInterval(CheckSession, ReqTime);
});

function CheckSession() {
    $.post('@Url.Action("SessionInfo","Home")', null, function () {
        console.log("Time");
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult SessionInfo()
    {

        if (Session["LoginUserName"]==null)
        {
             return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }


    }
```

This code does not re-direct to the Home/Index. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you checked your browser console and network tab, any error? Is call happening?

Comment: You are returning the content of index home on the $post. If you print the result of it, you'll notice it

Comment: No errors. Even in the debugging mode, the control seems to hit the RedirectToAction("Index","Home"). But redirection does not occur. Thanks @PSK

Comment: @DianaYsabel you are correct. Can you suggest an alternative to redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Javascript instead ,since redirect from server side need a post back

You can check session by controller and return a value to figure out if session end or not

```
 function CheckSession() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("SessionInfo", "Home")"
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data === true) {
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
        }
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert('Error');
    });
}
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult SessionInfo()
        {

            if (Session["LoginUserName"] == null)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This code for explaining

Comment: Hi, @Ahmed, I might be doing something wrong as my browser console shows Internal Server Error. `Login:41 GET http://localhost:56599/Home/SessionInfo 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-1.8.2.js:8430
ajax @ jquery-1.8.2.js:7982
CheckSession @ Login:41`

Answer (score 0):

By making those session checking ajax request you just extend life-span of the user session.

If you would like to inform browser that user session has end I recommend to implement a `SignalR` service to have direct communication ( push capability ) between server and the browser ( realtime ).

Implement a `SignalR` service,
Create a `session_end` method in your `global.asax` file, in the `session_end` send a message to user browser that your session has end.

Just it

Comment: I might be wrong but, global.asax only works when the session state mode is "InProc". I, on the other hand am using state mode as "StateServer". Thanks @Ali

Comment: Hi, @Ali I would like some more insight into your approach as I am quite new to MVC .Net. Thanks in advance.